# getJSON/ajax get for element inside spring form tag doesnt work

Tags: jquery, json, forms, spring, jsp

I am facing a strange issue on a rather simple functionality. I have placed an "input:submit" element inside my spring "form" tag and am performing getJSON functionality on it. But it doesnt work until I place the element outside the form tag. I am not able to get the answer for it. Could someone shed some light on this really simple behaviour which I should be knowing?

Here are the relavent codes.

My jsp page (This is working)

```
 <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
 <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
 <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
 <html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js">        </script>
<title>Spring 3 MVC Series - Contact Manager</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    .data, .data td {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        margin: 2px;
        padding: 2px;
    }
    .data th {
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #5C82FF;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Contact Manager</h2>


<table>
<tr>
    <td>
     <h2>Random Person Generator</h2>
     <input type="submit" id="randomPerson" value="Get Random Person" /><br/><br/>
     <div id="personResponse"> </div>
    </td>
</tr>

</table>



<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#randomPerson').click(function() {
            $.getJSON('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/contacts/random', function(contact) {
                  $('#personResponse').text(contact.firstname);
                });

        });
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/contacts/random", method = RequestMethod.GET ,headers = "Accept=*/*")
public @ResponseBody Contact randomPerson() {
    Contact contact = contactService.getRandom();
    System.out.println(contact.getFirstname());

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(contact);
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return contact;
}
```

I am using ObjectMapper just for my verification.

This is my contact class.

```
 package com.org.hemanth.contacts.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="CONTACTS")
public class Contact {

@Id
@Column(name="ID")
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
private String firstname;

@Column(name="LASTNAME")
private String lastname;

@Column(name="EMAIL")
private String email;

@Column(name="TELEPHONE")
private String telephone;


public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public String getTelephone() {
    return telephone;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
    this.telephone = telephone;
}
public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}
public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}
public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

 }
```

Now if I put the table inside a spring "form" tag with method="get" and commandName="contact", the json data is not displayed at all. It surely goes to the controller both the time, but I dont have a clue what happens when it returns.

Also, I have this warning popping up in my browser inspect element as "please use preventDefault" , not sure what or where to use it.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

Because your form get sumitted when you place it in form

**Solution 1**

supress the submission of form on buttom click

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#randomPerson').click(function(e) {
        $.getJSON('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/contacts/random', function(contact) {
              $('#personResponse').text(contact.firstname);
            });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

**Solution 2**

change your input type to button instead of submit, so on clicking on it form doesn't get submitted

```
<input type="button" id="randomPerson" value="Get Random Person" /><br/><br/>
```

Comment: ok. But if I put method = "get" then the form should not submit right? But it submits, why is that? Does the type "submit" in the button over rides it?

Comment: it doesn't matter, if method is GET or POST , form always get submitted on clicking submit button.This both are ways to submit how your data will be submitted

Answer (score 1):

If you add your form-tag your form will be submitted if you klick on the button. Before the form is submitted your query click handler will kick in, do his json stuff, get some json from your controller - and then the form will be submitted and a new and fresh version of your page will be getted.

To prevent this you have to break this default event handling after your click handler has done his work.

Change

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#randomPerson').click(function() {
        $.getJSON('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/contacts/random', function(contact) {
              $('#personResponse').text(contact.firstname);
            });

    });
});
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#randomPerson').click(function(evt) {
        $.getJSON('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/contacts/random', function(contact) {
              $('#personResponse').text(contact.firstname);
            });
        evt.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

The

```
evt.preventDefault();
```

will prevent, well, the default event handling so the form submit will not be sent.

Comment: ok. But if I put method = "get" then the form should not submit right? But it submits, why is that? Does the type "submit" in the button over rides it?

Comment: There is no reason why a form could not be submitted by get. You will maybe run in trouble if you use get (e.g. maximum path length accepted by the server) but if you like you can get a form - at least as long as you don't try to upload files, but that's another story...

Comment: Some background: http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/general-miscellaneous/html-get-vs-post/

Comment: ok... So what was happening was, when I gave button type "submit" it behaved like a "post" and retrieved fresh jsp everytime even though I gave "get" in the form method attribute correct?

Comment: Sort of. It didn't behave like post, it submits the form (by get, not by post). But you are right that a fresh jsp is retrieved. It' s some sort of a race condition: Both, the form submission and the ajax call are executed and the fresh jsp fetched by the submission 'wins'.